# How to generate Har file from java using selenium webdriver without autoexport?

Tags: java, selenium, firebug, har, netexport

I am using netexport api with firebug in selenium for automation . 

There are two cases.

1. **Auto export**: I have enabled this option in java with FF custom profile and the har file is automatically generating once the page load done. I am able to parse the file also.

2.Some pages has Ajax calls and its updating the response in particular DIV . So I am not able to capture/save the har file for the particular ajax request(REST service) as the page is not loading. I want the request/response details. 
Is it possible to manually export the har file from selenium webdriver in java?

It would be good if we have any command/function in selenium webdriver(java) which will return har file or json string , we can call this whenever required. 
The auto export option generating har file for every time page load.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/http-archive-specification/73jf6K_FK3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found workaround for manual har file export from java using AutoIt script .

Need to enable the firebug plug in Firefox and net panel view will be displayed by default and we have option to manually export har file.
 By using Autoit tool we can record the manual export function and compile the script which will give .exe file we can call the exe file from java .

Comment: Can you provide the script here using Autoit?

Answer (score 2):

Use PhantomJS with BrowserMobProxy. PhantomJS helps us for JavaScript enabled pages. The following code works for HTTPS web addresses, too.

Place **'phantomjs.exe'** in C drive and you get the **'HAR-Information.har'** file in C drive itself.

Make sure you **DO NOT** put a **' / '** at the end of the url, like

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
```

It should be

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Otherwise, it won't work.

```
package makemyhar;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har;
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MakeMyHAR {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        //BrowserMobProxy
        BrowserMobProxy server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        server.start(0);
        server.setHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.getAllContentCaptureTypes());
        server.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
        server.newHar("Google");

        //PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS
        ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<>();
        cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=localhost:"+server.getPort());
        cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");

        //DesiredCapabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\phantomjs.exe");

        //WebDriver
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        //HAR
        Har har = server.getHar();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\HAR-Information.har");
        har.writeTo(fos);
        server.stop();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16383631)

Comment: @ShawnMehan Done. Why essential, I thought I'd put the whole thing even here. There's just one another stackoverflow page with the same thing.